# Get encoded password from database using spring security

Tags: spring

i 'am using spring security to authentification it works well but the problem when i want to show the password to user for example to change it. I obtained this result :
 userPassword :  $2a$10$ZeFKrfzQ9UEtzysleH6K5uov5DTmumnEOMdU7OKDZpnGfbY2gmDWW
how can i get the password and show it like that :
userPassword : ******

I'm new in spring. Thakns in advance  to give me an example, tutoriel or advice.

Comment: The password has been hashed (one way encrypted), you can't decrpty it.  The whole idea is that no one can get the password.  You can only see if the password offer matches what is in the database.

Comment: How many services have you seen over the internet that show the password to the user? That's a poor security practice. Just let the user change it, following a proper flow.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just a question : I can pass the encrypted password : ******  ie entered by  user to their account ??